# Problem with props.children in typescript useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

interface Products {
  id: number;
  product: string;
  price: number;
  children?: any; //I belive I need to change this to something else
}

export const ProductsContext = React.createContext<Products[] | any>([]);

export const Productsprovider = (props: Products) => {
  // If I choose Props: To any it works

  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Products[]>([
    {
      id: 1,
      product: 'toothpaste',
      price: 50
    }
  ]);

  return <ProductsContext.Provider value={[products, setProducts]}>{props.children}</ProductsContext.Provider>;
};

export default Productsprovider;
```

`Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Products': id, product, price`

If I choose to go with Props: any instead of the interface Products it works.

I'm surely missing something but I don't know what it is..

App.js

```
<Productsprovider>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <ShoppingList />
  </div>
</Productsprovider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed:

`export const Productsprovider = (props : Products) => {`

To:

`export const Productsprovider = ({children}: {children: ReactNode} ) => {`

and

```
<ProductsContext.Provider value={[products,setProducts]}>
{children}
</ProductsContext.Provider>)
```